bpf_ktime_get_ns Indicates a negative value of the obtained time
I use perf to sample the ebpf function, but I use bpf_ktime_get_ns to get the current second of the system found to be negative, I don't know why
SEC("perf_event")
int do_perf_event(struct bpf_perf_event_data *ctx) {
    u32 tgid = 0;
    u32 pid = 0;
    u64 id = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    pid = id;
    if ( pid == 0 )
        return 0;
    tgid = id >> 32;
    //create map key
    struct key_t key = {0};
    key.pid =tgid;
    u64 ts = bpf_ktime_get_ns();
    key.ntime= ts;
    bpf_perf_event_output((struct pt_regs *)ctx, &output_events, BPF_F_CURRENT_CPU, &key, sizeof(key));
    return 0;
}

reader, err := perf.NewReader(objs.bpfMaps.OutputEvents, 10000 * int(unsafe.Sizeof(bpfSchedEventT{})))
for {
    record, err := reader.Read()
    var event bpfSchedEventT
    if err := binary.Read(bytes.NewBuffer(record.RawSample), binary.LittleEndian, &event); err != nil {
         continue
     }

     fmt.Println(event.Pid,event.Ntime)
}

 pid          bpf_ktime_get_ns 2304287 -4952501534609899520 2304287 -4951917187129409536 2304287 -4909853600282312704 2304287 -4909930153779396608 2304287 -4909776359590461440 2304287 -4909124929015775232 2305278 -4908938351341469696 2134146 -4909027119725543424 4026847 -4908622722784821248
I don't know why the time is negative

key.ntime I set to 22222, and perf read is not 22222

I found that all the other fields except the first pid was good had problematic data

The first digit in the struct is all good

Could you share the C and Go definitions of the struct used to pass data to userspace?

c: struct data_t {
u64 ntime;
u32 pid;
};        \n  go: type bpfSchedEventT struct {
Ntime int64
Pid int32
}

Not when the ntime is below the pid

Did you try with unsigned types for the Golang counterpart?

I didn't try to unsigned types for the Golang counterpart

When I put the u64 on the top
struct key_t { u64 ntime; u32 pid; };

Was this posted as an answer by mistake?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
